# Fixing Traceback (most recent call last): in Bar code reader using Python

Tags: python, barcode-scanner

I used the following code to get the reading from a USB bar code reader connected to a raspberry pi.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys


def barcode_reader():
    hid = {4: 'a', 5: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'd', 8: 'e', 9: 'f', 10: 'g', 11: 'h', 12: 'i', 13: 'j', 14: 'k', 15: 'l', 16: 'm',
           17: 'n', 18: 'o', 19: 'p', 20: 'q', 21: 'r', 22: 's', 23: 't', 24: 'u', 25: 'v', 26: 'w', 27: 'x', 28: 'y',
           29: 'z', 30: '1', 31: '2', 32: '3', 33: '4', 34: '5', 35: '6', 36: '7', 37: '8', 38: '9', 39: '0', 44: ' ',
           45: '-', 46: '=', 47: '[', 48: ']', 49: '\\', 51: ';', 52: '\'', 53: '~', 54: ',', 55: '.', 56: '/'}

    hid2 = {4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'D', 8: 'E', 9: 'F', 10: 'G', 11: 'H', 12: 'I', 13: 'J', 14: 'K', 15: 'L', 16: 'M',
            17: 'N', 18: 'O', 19: 'P', 20: 'Q', 21: 'R', 22: 'S', 23: 'T', 24: 'U', 25: 'V', 26: 'W', 27: 'X', 28: 'Y',
            29: 'Z', 30: '!', 31: '@', 32: '#', 33: '$', 34: '%', 35: '^', 36: '&', 37: '*', 38: '(', 39: ')', 44: ' ',
            45: '_', 46: '+', 47: '{', 48: '}', 49: '|', 51: ':', 52: '"', 53: '~', 54: '<', 55: '>', 56: '?'}

    fp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb') 

    ss = ""
    shift = False

    done = False

    while not done:
        # Get the character from the HID
        buffer = fp.read(8)
        for c in buffer:
            if ord(c) > 0:

                #  40 is carriage return which signifies
               
                if int(ord(c)) == 40:
                    done = True
                    break;

                
                #  use the hid2 characters.
                if shift:

                    # If it is a '2' then it is the shift key
                    if int(ord(c)) == 2:
                        shift = True

                    # if not a 2 then lookup the mapping
                    else:
                        ss += hid2[int(ord(c))]
                        shift = False

                #  If not shifted then use
                #  the hid characters

                else:

                    # If it is a '2' then it is the shift key
                    if int(ord(c)) == 2:
                        shift = True

                    # if not a 2 then lookup the mapping
                    else:
                        ss += hid[int(ord(c))]
    return ss


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        while True:
            barcode_reader()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
```

when this is executed, it get the following error message.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\buddhika\Desktop\barcode_test.py", line 66, in <module>
    barcode_reader()
File "C:\Users\buddhika\Desktop\barcode_test.py", line 16, in barcode_reader
    fp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb')
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/dev/hidraw0'
```

I tried the methods given in the internet to fix first error, but still the issue is there. The second error was corrected.
Why the first error message still comes and how to fix this.

Comment: Please [edit] to include the _full_ error traceback, not just the first lines, as the whole message contains valuable information

Comment: @G.Anderson the full error traceback was included. the second error I could resolved. But the problem is the first error which is still coming.

Comment: Your question is confusing, There is only one error shown, telling that `barcode_reader()` threw an error, because while attempting to execute it, `'/dev/hidraw0'` could not be found by the system to be opened by the function. A single error traceback is just _tracing_ the error _back_ through the code execution. The top shows where in the code the error is finally reported, the last line (`FileNotFoundError`) tells what the error is